# Orbits of a $GL_{n}×GL_{n}×M_{n}(F)$ action group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

There's an exercise on Permutations Groups of Dixon:

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all $n × n $ matrices over a field $F$ and let $G = GL_{n}(F) × GL_{n}(F)$ where $GL_{n}(F)$ is the group of all $n × n$ invertible
matrices over $F$.

There is an action of $G$ on $\Omega$ defined by $a(x,y) := 
x^{T}ay$ ($a,x^{T}ay$ in $\Omega$ and $(x,y)$ in $G$)

I have to show that $G$ has exactly $n+1$ orbits and describe these. I've tried to divide de problem in two cases: when $a$ is invertible and when isn't, but actually I don't know if that's correct or what more to do.

Also I have to describe de stabilizer of a chosen point from each orbit.

I think there's facts from elementary linear algebra, but really I have no idea what should use.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! I'd start by considering how the rank of a matrix is affected when multiplied by an invertible matrix (from either side), and then take it from there.